# Trouble getting output from API

Tags: php, dogecoin-api

I'm currently building a site that will offer services that customers can pay for in Dogecoin. I am using DogeAPI and [these example checkout scripts](https://www.dogeapi.com/checkout_example) to try and build my checkout pages.

The problem is I can't get the address ($new_address) to echo to the page. When I run the script all that shows up is "Please pay 1000 DOGE to to receive your item. It may take up to 10 minutes to confirm your payment." When I log into my dashboard on DogeAPI, it doesn't show that any addresses were created.

I have a feeling that I need some sort of code that will wait until file_get_ contents() is finished and then start the JSON decoding. My code is below.

**NOTE**: I do have the API key in my code, I just obviously removed it before posting the code here.

```
//set to your API_KEY
$api_key = 'MY API HERE';

//set this to your users id
//must be alphanumeric only
$user_id = 'test123';

//set this to the amount the item costs
$amount_doge = '1000';

//send a request to the API to make a new payment address
//put info about the request in
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.dogeapi.com/wow/?api_key=$api_key&a=get_new_address&address_label=$user_id");

if($response !== 'Bad Query' && $response !== '') {
    $new_address = json_decode($response);
    //insert the new pending payment
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `api_payments`
                           (`payment_label`,`payment_address`,`paid`,`amount`)
                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$new_address', '0', '$amount_doge')");

    //give them the address or echo a widget here
    //for this example we will just echo an address
    echo "Please pay $amount_doge DOGE to $response to receive your item. It may take up to 10 minutes to confirm your payment.";

} else {
    echo 'There was a problem processing your order.';
}
```

Comment: You should test the return from file_get_contents() for false instead of the empty string: `$response !== false` (or in addition to testing for empty string, if dogeapi might return that)

Comment: Does it store the information in your database table api_payments?

Comment: "The problem is I can't get the address ($new_address) to echo to the page." Where are you trying to do this? It's not in the sample you provided.